Optimizing FastAPI for Multiple Requests with Limited GPU Memory
I have developed an app using Fast API as the backend and JavaScript for the frontend.
Now, I want to handle multiple requests on my server, considering that I am using large language models like Mistral 7B and some information retrieval (IR) systems for my RAG chatbot.
I know that when a user asks a query, there is this pipeline: the IR retrieves the 10 most relevant documents and sends them to the frontend. After that, the frontend automatically sends another request, where the backend generates the answer (streaming it token by token). Then, another request is automatically sent to the backend, which is a verification model that checks if the answer is correct or not (for my question, it doesn't matter how this model works).
This is the code in javascript just to give you a quick overview:
const document_response = await fetch('http://18.198.26.251:5001/query/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.context.user.token, 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query: value,
                                   search_type: search_type,
                                   limit : numDocuments,
                                   filter_date_lte: endDate,
                                   filter_date_gte: startDate,
                                   lex_par:lex_parameter,
                                   semantic_par:sem_parameter,
                                })
        });
        
        const document_found = await document_response.json()
        console.log(document_found)
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            questions: prevState.questions.map((q, i) => (
                i === prevState.questions.length - 1 ? { ...q, document_found } : q
            )),
        }));

        
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
        
        const response = await fetch('http://18.198.26.251:5001/stream_tokens/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.context.user.token, 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query: value,
                                   temperature:temperature
                                })
        });
    
        const processResult = async (result) => {
            if (result.done) {
                //this.setState({  });
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    questions: prevState.questions.map((q, i) => (
                        i === prevState.questions.length - 1 ? { ...q, status: "fetching_verification", loading:true} : q
                    )),
                }));
                this.postVerification(this.state.questions[this.state.questions.length - 1].result);
                return;
            }

As you can see, when you ask a question, the frontend sends three requests.
Now, the problem is that I want to handle multiple requests.
So, if I have two users, A and B, I want to ensure that if A and B send query requests, the operation /query of A is executed first, followed by the stream_token and verification operations of A, and finally the operation /query of B.
I have tried to extend the number of workers, but considering that I don't have enough memory on my GPU, I cannot use this feature of FastAPI.
This is the code in the backend that I tried to implement, but it doesn't work:
async def add_task_to_beginning(queue: asyncio.Queue, task):
    temp_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await temp_queue.put(task)
    while not queue.empty():
        item = await queue.get()
        await temp_queue.put(item)
    return temp_queue


# Semaphore to limit concurrent workers
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(PARALLEL_PROCESSES)

# Queue to hold incoming requests
queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def worker():
    while True:
        # Get the next task from the queue
        print("QUEUE = ", queue)
        task = await queue.get()
        print("TASK = ", task)
        try:
            await semaphore.acquire()
            # Process the task 
            await task()
        finally:
            semaphore.release()
            queue.task_done()

documents_found = {}

async def answer_generation(query: Query, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    global documents_found
    
    #Authorize.jwt_required()
    search_query = query.query
    
    print("THE SEARCH QUERY IS ",search_query)
    print(f"Search type {query.search_type}, Date {query.filter_date_lte}, {query.filter_date_gte}")
    print(f"Param lex = {query.lex_par}, sem_param = {query.semantic_par}, limit = {query.limit}")
    if not search_query:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Query parameter 'search' is missing")
    
    try:
        start = time.time()
        documents = query_parser.execute_query(search_query, query.search_type, lex_parameter=query.lex_par, 
                                                semantic_parameter=query.semantic_par, limit=query.limit,
                                                pubdate_filter_lte=query.filter_date_lte, 
                                                pubdate_filter_gte=query.filter_date_gte,stopwords_preprocessing=query.stop_word)
        
        documents_found = documents
        
        return documents
    except Exception as e:
        #Handle a specific type of exception
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="{}".format(str(e)))




async def stream_tokens(request:Request, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    
    data = await request.json()
    search_query = data['query']
    temperature = data['temperature']
    try:

        documents_string = convert_documents(documents_found)
        
        mistral_input = f"{search_query}\nPapers:\n" + documents_string
        
        print(mistral_input)
        print("")
        print("")
        
        return StreamingResponse(generate(mistral_input,temperature,tokenizer, model_mistral, device),media_type='text/event-stream')
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="{}".format(str(e)))


async def verification_answer(answer: VerificationInput, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    answer_complete = answer.text
    print("ANSWER =\n",answer_complete)
    pmid_claim = split_text_by_pubmed_references(answer_complete)
    print("PMID CLAIM = ",pmid_claim)
    claim_pmid_list = verification_format(pmid_claim)
    #print("Results of splitting...")
    #print(claim_pmid_list)
   
    async def generate_results():
        for result in verification_claim(claim_pmid_list, documents_found, verification_model, verification_tokenizer, model):
            json_result = json.dumps(result)
            if result != {}:
                print("RESULT = ",result)
                print("RESULT = ",result['result'], type(result["result"]))
                print("-"*50)

            if result != {} and NO_REFERENCE_NUMBER in result["result"]:
                # beacuse the operation is so much faster
                print("ENTRO E ASPETTO")
                await asyncio.sleep(0.3)

            yield json_result
        
    
    return StreamingResponse(generate_results(), media_type="application/json")
    

@app.post("/query")
async def query(query: Query, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    global queue
    task = lambda: answer_generation(query, current_user)
    queue = await add_task_to_beginning(queue, task)
    return await queue.join()  # Ensure that the task is processed before returning

@app.post("/stream_tokens")
async def streaming(request: Request, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    global queue
    task = lambda: stream_tokens(request, current_user)
    queue = await add_task_to_beginning(queue, task)
    return await queue.join()  # Ensure that the task is processed before returning

@app.post("/verification_answer")
async def verification(request: Request, current_user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    global queue
    task = lambda: verification_answer(request, current_user)
    queue = await add_task_to_beginning(queue, task)
    return await queue.join() 

I want a way to handle multiple processes in a sequence, so that the operations to give an answer to user A are executed first, and then the operations to give an answer to user B.
